# Good Motherboard for 16/16/4 configurations?

Tags: motherboard, pci-express

I am looking for a board that supports 16/16/4 configurations (lga 1366 of course). For 2 graphic cards in SLI (250gts twin frozr) and a [revodrive](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820227578&cm_re=revodrive-_-20-227-578-_-Product) (not bought yet).

This board seem alright for my needs:

- [ASUS Sabertooth X58](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131665&cm_re=sabertooth-_-13-131-665-_-Product)

But I am afraid it's going to be too tight for both of my graphic cards. Do anyone know any other board that would do the job?

Preferably asus motherboards, as they are the most stable boards I know.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off-topic as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two main competitions for the setup I need seems to be the p6t and the sabertooth

p6t:
http://www.pcvonline.com/productDetails.aspx?prodID=10940

sabertooth:
http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131665&cm_re=sabertooth--13-131-665--Product

Comment: no one has an opinion on this? :O

Comment: SU isn't for buying recommendations.